# Zimbra not releasing space

Tags: postfix-mta, zimbra

We are using Zimbra 8.0 collaboration server open source edition. (Release 8.0.0_GA_5434.RHEL6_64_20120907144639 CentOS6_64 FOSS edition ) on centos6.

While we deleting an Account or Emptying Folder , the free Space in HDD is not increasing.
For Example, If we deleted an account having 10GB size, only 1GB is getting added to Total free space of HDD.

In detail, I Emptied an Account having size 10.1GB.
The Space occupied by the Store Folder before deleting is 10.1 GB
/opt/zimbra/store/0/443 - 10.1 GB
After Emptying inbox folder the size of the store folder reduced to 100 MB.
/opt/zimbra/store/0/443 - 100 MB
(Emptied using command zmmailbox -z -m xxx@xxx.com emptyFolder /Inbox)

But NO change in "df" output. The Total free space remains the same.

Accordingly, Space is not releasing while deleting an account.

Anyone Please help to find a solution in this issue.  What need to be done to get free space added to HDD. Help needed.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, please post it at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your dumpster settings are, though they could be determined by a command like this:

zmprov ga xxx@xxx.com |grep Dumpster

zimbraDumpsterEnabled: TRUE
zimbraDumpsterPurgeEnabled: TRUE
zimbraDumpsterUserVisibleAge: 10d
zimbraMailDumpsterLifetime: 10d

I suspect that the messages are sticking around in the dumpster though.  You can clean them out with a command like this:

zmmailbox -z -m xxx@xxx.com -A emptyDumpster

Comment: In our server "zimbraDumpsterEnabled" is FALSE.

zimbraDumpsterEnabled: FALSE
zimbraDumpsterPurgeEnabled: TRUE
zimbraDumpsterUserVisibleAge: 30d
zimbraMailDumpsterLifetime: 30d

We also ran the command zmmailbox -z -m xxx@xxx.com -A emptyDumpster, but no change in free space.!

could you please give your suggestions..!